# Cannot reach https://pkg.julialang.org/registries --> Very long installation times for new packages in Julia 1.9.1 for macOS with Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, julia

When I try to add a new package (something that in version 1.8.5 was super fast) now I have VERY long waiting times.
OBS: In my computer the internet connection is working fine.

Resolving package versions...
┌ Warning: could not download https://pkg.julialang.org/registries
│ exception = RequestError: HTTP/2 301 (Connection timeout after 30002 ms) while requesting https://pkg.julialang.org/registries

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.9.1
Commit 147bdf428cd (2023-06-07 08:27 UTC)
Platform Info:
OS: macOS (arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0)
CPU: 8 × Apple M1
WORD_SIZE: 64
LIBM: libopenlibm
LLVM: libLLVM-14.0.6 (ORCJIT, apple-m1)
Threads: 1 on 4 virtual cores

Installed Julia from https://julialang.org/downloads/ downloading the .dmg file.

Comment: please include what code you have ran- including the package you are trying to add